# selenium not showing pop up when script is running

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using python-selenium bindings to automate webpage. I am using following line of code to press `ENTER` button and invoke a pop up:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath_of_element").send_keys(u'\ue007')
```

The Test Case is pass but it donot invoke the pop-up when the script is running. DO anyone know why?

Comment: What do you mean by invoke a pop up??? Please elaborate your question... It is not clear..

Comment: Actually I am trying to press ENTER on a button using following line of code:
driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath_of_element").send_keys(u'\ue007')
when ENTER is pressed on that button it should invoke a pop up. But it is not doing so. The Test case is pass as per the logs generated by webdriver but it do not invoke the pop up.

Comment: Have you tried this `driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath_of_element").click()`

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `click()` instead of `send_keys()` as below :-

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath_of_element").click()
```

**Edited** :- if in your case pop-up occurred by keyboard events try as below :-

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath_of_element").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Hope it helps..:)

Comment: click donot work on that page only keyboard events like enter and navigation key works

Comment: @user1537127 did you tried already using `click()`?? I think this will work.. if already not tried, please tried once and let me know..

Comment: yes i tried.... click donot work.. actually it was my mistake it was pointing to diff xpath thanku.. good day:)